# Create folders when creating a new WPF project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I would like to find a way to create four folders when I create a new WPF app/lib. Those four folders would be DAO, Model, ViewModel and View.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is described here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx). Creating project templates is standart VS functionality since VS2005